# Redirect to previous page after login Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, router

I'm trying to make it so that when the user tries to visit a page that requires authentication (eg: 'profile'), the user should be sent to the login page, and once logged in it should be sent back to the page he was visiting.

Like when you visit an instagram profile from the browser, to like you have to log in, and once done you are sent back to the photo you were looking at.

PS. I'm a beginner, so please be clear where I write, Thanks.

```js
LOGIN

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    Button: () => import("../components/ui/Button.vue"),
    Spinner: () => import("../components/ui/Spinner.vue"),
    InputText: () => import("../components/ui/InputText.vue")
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["authStore"]),
    computedWidth() {
      if (window.innerWidth < 420)
        return { wrapper: "width: 82.5%", icon: "width: 24px" };
      return { wrapper: "width: 50%", icon: "width: 20px" };
    },
    currentYear() {
      return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    input: "",
    isCodeRequested: false,
    error: "",
    token: "",
    isLoading: false,
    socialMock: {
      Instagram:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Instagram_icon.png/2048px-Instagram_icon.png",
      Facebook:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png/1024px-Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png",
      Google:
        "https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-webinar-optimizing-for-success-google-business-webinar-13.png"
    }
  }),

  methods: {
    handleError(error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.$store.commit("auth_error", error);
      this.error = error.message;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    async authRequest() {
      try {
        this.isLoading = true;
        await this.$http.post(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "/login/passwordless/request",
          { email: this.input, operator: false }
        );
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isCodeRequested = true;
        this.input = "";
      } catch (error) {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    },
    async verifyCode() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$http.get(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL +
            "/login/passwordless/verify/" +
            this.input
        );
        return await response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    },
    async handleLogin() {
      try {
        if (!this.isCodeRequested) {
          this.authRequest();
          return;
        }
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.$store.commit("auth_request");
        const credentials = await this.verifyCode();
        const { token_type, access_token } = await credentials.data;
        const token = `${token_type} ${access_token}`;
        this.$store.commit("authStore/SET_TOKEN", token);
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common = {
          Authorization: token
        };
        this.$router.push("/");
        this.isLoading = false;
      } catch (error) {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    },
    async login() {
      try {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.$store.commit("auth_request");
        const response = await this.$http.post(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "/login",
          {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          }
        );
        const { token_type, access_token } = await response.data;
        const token = `${token_type} ${access_token}`;
        this.$store.commit("authStore/SET_TOKEN", token);
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common = {
          Authorization: token
        };
        this.$router.push("/");
        this.isLoading = false;
      } catch (error) {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    },
    async socialLogin(type) {
      switch (type) {
        default:
          alert(`login via ${type} is not supported, please come back later.`);
          break;
      }
    }
  },

  async mounted() {
    this.error = "";
    try {
      if (!this.$route.query.token) return;
      console.log(this.$route.query.token);
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error.message;
    }
  }
};
</script>

ROUTER, INDEX.JS
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/search/:oid?",
    name: "search",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ "../views/Search.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/servizio/:id/:slug?",
    name: "public-service",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "public-service" */ "../views/PublicService.vue"
      ),
    meta: {
      //noAuth: true,
      keepQuery: true,
      withAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/operatore/:id/:slug?",
    name: "public-operator",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "public-operator" */ "../views/PublicOperator.vue"
      ),
    meta: {
      //noAuth: true,
      keepQuery: true,
      withAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/offerta/:id/:slug?",
    name: "public-offer",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "public-offer" */ "../views/PublicOffer.vue"),
    meta: {
      //noAuth: true,
      keepQuery: true,
      withAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path:
      "/estetisti-certificati/:locationCity/:locationLat,:locationLong/:services/:userSex/:operatorSex/:oid?",
    name: "search-public",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "search-public" */ "../views/SearchPublic.vue"
      ),
    meta: {
      noAuth: true,
      keepQuery: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ "../views/Dashboard.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: "home",
        path: "/",
        component: () => import("../views/Home.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "profile",
        path: "profile",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "user-profile" */ "../views/Profile.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "location",
        path: "location",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "location" */ "../views/Location.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "settings",
        path: "settings",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "settings" */ "../views/Settings.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "shop",
        path: "shop",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "shop" */ "../views/Shop.vue"),
        meta: {
          operator: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: "wallet",
        path: "wallet",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "wallet" */ "../views/Wallet.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "reservations",
        path: "reservations/:rid?",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "reservations" */ "../views/Reservations.vue"
          )
      },
      {
        name: "user-profile",
        path: "conversations/user/:uid?",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ "../views/Conversations.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "operator-profile",
        path: "conversations/operator/:oid?",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ "../views/Conversations.vue")
      },
      {
        name: "conversations",
        path: "conversations/:cid?",
        props: true,
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ "../views/Conversations.vue")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: () => import("../views/Login.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

// keep query params between redirects
/*
function hasQueryParams(route) {
  return !!Object.keys(route.query).length;
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.matched.some(record => record.meta.keepQuery)) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  if (!hasQueryParams(to) && hasQueryParams(from)) {
    router.push({ ...to, query: from.query }).catch(() => {});
  } else {
    next();
  }
});*/

// auth check
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to === "login") return;
  if (!store.state.authStore.token) {
    window.location.href.includes("/login")
      ? next()
      : (window.location.href = process.env.VUE_APP_LANDING_URL + "/login");
  }

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.noAuth)) {
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      store
        .dispatch("update")
        .catch(() => {
          next();
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response && response.status === 200) next("/");
        });
    } else {
      next("/");
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn && 1 * store.state.user.level > 0) {
      // user is logged in and is support
      Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common = {
        Authorization: store.state.authStore.token
      };
      next();
    }

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        return store
          .dispatch("forceUpdate")
          .then(() => resolve(true))
          .catch(() => {
            reject();
          });
      }

      store.dispatch("update").catch(() => {
        window.location.href = process.env.VUE_APP_LANDING_URL;
      });

      return resolve();
    })
      .then(() => {
        Sentry.setUser({ id: store.state.user.id });
        // user is logged in

        if (1 * store.state.user.level > 0) {
          // user is support
          next();
        }

        if (
          !store.getters.isOperator &&
          to.matched.some(record => record.meta.operator)
        ) {
          // is a route for operators and user isn't operator
          next("/");
          return;
        }

        // is a user route
        next();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        window.location.href = process.env.VUE_APP_LANDING_URL;
      });
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.withAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn && 1 * store.state.user.level > 0) {
      return;
    }

    new Promise(resolve => {
      if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        return store
          .dispatch("forceUpdate")
          .then(() => resolve(true))
          .catch(() => {
            resolve(false);
          });
      }

      return resolve();
    }).then(() => {
      Sentry.setUser({ id: store.state.user.id });

      if (1 * store.state.user.level > 0) {
        return;
      }

      if (
        !store.getters.isOperator &&
        to.matched.some(record => record.meta.operator)
      ) {
        return;
      }

      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

```html
This is the login.vue

<form @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
            <label
              for=""
              >Your email</label
            >
            <InputText
              :placeholder="isCodeRequested ? 'Your code' : 'Your email'"
              :type="isCodeRequested ? 'text' : 'email'"
              :name="isCodeRequested ? 'code' : 'email'"
              v-model="input"
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              :disabled="isLoading || input.length < 3"
            >
              <Spinner v-if="$store.state.status === 'loading'" />
              <span v-else>
                {{ isCodeRequested ? "accedi" : "Ask for a code" }}
              </span>
            </Button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the login is done successfully use [go](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/router.html#Methods-go) method from `$router` object:

```js
this.$router.go(-1) //to go back
```

Comment: Thanks, where should I write it? I'm a newbie, and I have no idea where to write this.

Comment: In `login` method in the place of `this.$router.push("/")`

Comment: Already tried, it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a user was on `/home/dashboard` and for some reason, usually due to a `401` or in your case due to an authentication requirement was redirected to login page.

Here you send the user to login page in router guard but do it with an identifier of the page which the user wanted to access or was on:

So for example he accessed `/home/profile`

```
next('/login?redirect=profile')
```

Now when you are on the login page your url (localhost) will look like this:

```
http://localhost:<port>/login?redirect=profile
```

Now when user enters `username` and `password`.

Instead of taking them to the default route, take them the `profile` route:

```
if (this.$route.query.redirect){
 this.$router.push({ path: `/home/${this.$route.query.redirect}` })
} else {
 // Your default action for example push '/'
}
```

Here `this.$route.query.redirect = 'profile'`

Make sure your route name matches with the value of `redirect`.

Comment: Hmmm sorry, but I didn't understand. What should I write, and where? Thanks for your patience.